# How to get Xcode style autocomplete in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, autocomplete

I've used both Xcode and Visual Studio extensively over the past year, and the one thing I miss about Xcode when using VS is the autocompletion suggestions while typing in the middle of words. Let me explain:

In Xcode, autocomplete suggestions (the little dropdown that appears as you begin to type) work from any point in the word. So lets say you start typing something, click somewhere else, then get back to what you were typing; Xcode will happily keep giving you autocomplete suggestions. If you do this in VS, you'll find that autocomplete suggestions don't appear. You have to delete what you typed and start over again. If you were typing a method, you have to erase up to and including the dot, re-type the dot, and only then do you get the suggestions. This is very annoying when going from Xcode to VS. Is there any way to enable Xcode style autocomplete suggestions in VS? I've googled but all I've come up with are plugins like Visual Assist X, which are not free and have a bunch of other features I'm not sure I absolutely need. I'd like something that would solve this specific issue, preferably free.

Comment: There is no free way to do this.

Comment: Resharper adds this, but it isn't free.

Comment: A video link could help explain.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't ctrl + spacebar doing the trick? It enables autocomplete when used.
There might be something more advanced you are after tho.

Comment: It seems to autocomplete to the first thing VS thinks you meant; it does not give me the suggestion list.